# Yii2: Projects area does not exist - cannot write project in reportico

Tags: php, yii, yii2, reportico

after installing yii2 reportico module and trying to enter an admin password, this error appears:

```
Projects area does not exist - cannot write project
```

the configuration variable "path_to_projects" is pointing to a projects folder which is exists.

how can i solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I got this error until I changed the following file:

```
vendor\reportico\yii2-reportico\components\reportico.php
```

Line 5468

From:

```
$proj_parent = find_best_location_in_include_path($this->admin_projects_folder);
```

To:

```
$proj_parent = $this->admin_projects_folder;
```

Something in the find_best_location_in_include_path() function in the swutil.php file does not like the path supplied and is returning nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when seting up repotico for yii2 and i solved by Changing :

```
$proj_parent = find_best_location_in_include_path( $this->admin_projects_folder);  
--which is around line 5737(notepad++)
```

to:

```
$proj_parent = $this->admin_projects_folder;
```

and error was gone.